# is having millions of tables and millions of rows within them a common practice in MySQL database design?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am doing database design for an upcoming web app, and I was wondering from anybody profusely using mysql in their current web apps if this sort of design is efficient for a web app for lets say 80,000 users.

1 DB

in DB, millions of tables for features for each user, and within each table, potentially millions of rows.

While this design is very dynamic and scales nicely, I was wondering two things.

1. Is this a common design in web applications today?
2. How would this perform, time wise, if querying millions of rows.
3. How does a DB perform if it contains MILLIONS of tables? (again, time wise, and is this even possible?)
4. if it performs well under above conditions, how could it perform under strenuous load, if all 80,000 users accessed the DB 20-30 times each for 10 -15 minute sessions every day?
5. how much server space would this require, very generally speaking (reiterating, millions of tables each containing potentially millions of rows with 10-15 columns filled with text)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't conceive of a scenario where it's a good idea to have millions of tables.

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong if you think you need millions of tables.

Comment: this is too hypothetical to answer effectively. depends on what the column definitions are, what type of data is stored, how heavily indexed it is, etc. etc. my intiution says there is a better way to architect this database than what you're describing..

Comment: Tables are generally generic and static structures for storing data.  If you're creating tables dynamically for each specific user you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Are you **really** talking about millions of tables?...or is just an hyperbole?

Comment: millions of table * millions of rows... let's say you have 500 bytes of data average per row. That's at least 2mil * 2mil * 500 = 2 PetaBytes. I don't know what you're architecting but that's *a lot* of data

Comment: In your previous [db-design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612173/is-this-sort-of-sql-structuring-in-a-mysql-database-efficient-in-a-real-world) question you were considering 80K databases (one for each user). Now, you are with 1 db but millions of tables per user. That's one step in the right direction. Hopefully, you'll end with a small number of tables.

Comment: Just common sense says that something wrong elsewhere ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1 - Definitely not.  Almost anyone you ask will tell you millions of tables is a terrible idea.

2 - Millions of ROWS is common, so just fine.

3 - Probably terribly, **especially if the queries are written by someone who thinks it's OK to have millions of tables**.  That tells me this is someone who doesn't understand databases very well.

4 - See #3

5 - Impossible to tell.  You will have a lot of extra overhead from the extra tables as they all need extra metadata.  Space needed will depend on indexes and how wide the tables are, along with a lot of other factors.

**In short, this is a very very very seriously bad idea and you should not do it.**

Comment: exactly why I asked, just wanted to make sure. will do.

Answer (score 4):

Millions of rows is perfectly normal usage, and can respond quickly if properly optimized and indexed.

Millions of tables is an indication that you've made a major goof in how you've architected your application. Millions of rows times millions of tables times 80,000 users means what, 80 quadrillion records? I strongly doubt you have that much data.

Comment: I'm sorry because I am sure this is a very trivial question, but what exactly do you mean by 'indexed correctly' . Do you mean just ONE column for a PRIMARY key as an INDEX, auto incrementing? Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: Yes, there's more to it than that. If you were frequently searching for specific values in the `email` column, for example, you'd likely want an index on that column. There are also composite indexes, which are indexes on more than one column at a time. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization-indexes.html.

Answer (score 3):

Having millions of rows in a table is perfectly normal and MySQL can handle this easily, as long as you use appropriate indexes.

Having millions of tables on the other hand seems like a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said, don't forget that finding the right table based on the given table name also takes time. How much time? Well, this is internal to DBMS and likely not documented, but probably more than you think.

So, a query searching for a row can either take:

1. Time to find the table + time to find the row in a (relatively) small table.
2. **Or**, just the time to find a row in one large table.

The (2) is likely to be faster.

Also, frequently using different table names in your queries makes query preparation less effective.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of having millions of tables, I can't imagine that you actually designing millions of logically distinct tables. Rather, I would strongly suspect that you are creating tables dynamically based on data. That is, rather than create a FIELD for, say, the user id, and storing one or more records for each user, you are contemplating creating a new TABLE for each user id. And then you'll have thousands and thousands of tables that all have exactly the same fields in them. If that's what you're up to: Don't. Stop.

A table should represent a logical TYPE of thing that you want to store data for. You might make a city table, and then have one record for each city. One of the fields in the city table might indicate what country that city is in. DO NOT create a separate table for each country holding all the cities for each country. France and Germany are both examples of "country" and should go in the same table. They are not different kinds of thing, a France-thing and a Germany-thing.

Here's the key question to ask: What data do I want to keep in each record? If you have 1,000 tables that all have exactly the same columns, then almost surely this should be one table with a field that has 1,000 possible values. If you really seriously keep totally different information about France than you keep about Germany, like for France you want a list of provinces with capital city and the population but for Germany you want a list of companies with industry and chairman of the board of directors, then okay, those should be two different tables. But at that point the difference is likely NOT France versus Germany but something else.

Answer (score 0):

1] Look up dimensions and facts tables in database design. You can start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_model#Dimensional_model.

2] Be careful about indexing too much: for high write/update you don't want to index too much because that gets very expensive (think average case or worst case of balancing a b-tree). For high read tables, index only the fields you search by. for example in

```
select * from mutable where A ='' and B='';
```

you may want to index A and B

3] It may not be necessary to start thinking about replication. but since you are talking about 10^6 entries and tables, maybe you should.

So, instead of me telling you a flat no for the millions of tables question (and yes my answer is NO), I think a little research will serve you better. As far as millions of records, it hints that you need to start thinking about "scaling out" -- as opposed to "scaling up."

Answer (score -5):

SQL Server has many ways you can support large tables. You may find some help by splitting your indexes across multiple partitions (filegroups), placing large tables on their own filegroup, and indexes for the large table on another set of filegroups.

A filegroup is basically a separate drive. Each drive has its own dedicated read and write heads. The more drives the more heads are searching the indexes at a time and thus faster results finding your records.

Here is a page that talks in details about filegroups.

http://cm-bloggers.blogspot.com/2009/04/table-and-index-partitioning-in-sql.html

Comment: This is tagged `MySQL`.  Why would you give SQL Server-specific advice?

Comment: I am surprised that this was negatively rated since my post is based on the link I included above. The question was related to performance and if millions of rows do exist then using filegroups would be a MAJOR player in the solution...

Comment: Partitioning has multiple benefits:
• efficient use of the available disk capacity by controlling the placement of data from a single table or index across multiple disks.
• partitioning enables flexible management of larger tables Because partitions are mapped to filegroups, you can use SQL Server backup to backup just the filegroups that contain changed data.
• partitioning can make the loading new data a much faster procedure using the SWITCH option, which we’ll discuss shortly.
• perhaps **bold**most significantly, partitioning can improve query response times for users.

Comment: oh, I just realized the post talked about millions of TABLES...my post definitely does not support millions of TABLES. My post relates to millions of rows and performance.