# Database and App: (Very) Many tables or Much redundancy

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, bigdata

I am doing database design for an app which requires both transactional and analytical functionality of much data. The "data" has about

100 x TopEntity

each with about (variable)

1000 x MidEntities

each with about (variable and increasing with time)

10 000 x BottomEntitiesTypeA
100 000 x BottomEntitiesTypeB

So the application logic is very hierarchical, and queries (SELECT, INSERT, etc) of (Mid/Bottom)Entities always knows their parents.

One design choice for a database would be

1 table for each type of entity as:

```
CREATE TABLE toplevel (id VARCHAR(255), field1 VARCHAR(255), ..., fieldN VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY(id))
CREATE TABLE midLevel (parentId VARCHAR(255), id VARCHAR(255), field1 VARCHAR(255), ..., fieldN VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY(parentId, id))
CREATE TABLE bottomLevelA (grandParentId VARCHAR(255), parentId VARCHAR(255), id VARCHAR(255), field1 VARCHAR(255), ..., fieldN VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY(grandParentId, parentId, id))
CREATE TABLE bottomLevelB (grandParentId VARCHAR(255), parentId VARCHAR(255), id VARCHAR(255), field1 VARCHAR(255), ..., fieldN VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY(grandParentId, parentId, id))
```

Pros:
Simple, efficient analytical queries of bottomlevel entities
Cons:
redundancy, bottomlevel tables (type B in particular) have 2*100*1000*10000(0) entries to cross-reference parents, consuming 1(0) GB times size of 255 long string.
Also the filesize of the table can become large.

Instead an alternative is to design the database according to the application, creating tables dynamically and referncing them by name, such as

```
CREATE TABLE bottomLevelB+"FOR"+parentId+"AND"+grandParentId (id VARCHAR(255), field1 VARCHAR(255), ..., fieldN VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

Pros:
Less redundancy, analytical queries can be done in app/views (RAM) or datawarehouse layer
Cons:
100 000 tables and counting

Backround information can be found on database normalization (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) which seams to suggest the second design. Here on stackoverflow a similar question has been asked ([is having millions of tables and millions of rows within them a common practice in MySQL database design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845156/is-having-millions-of-tables-and-millions-of-rows-within-them-a-common-practice)) but I find the answer to:

QUESTION: "How does a DB perform if it contains MILLIONS of tables? (again, time wise, and is this even possible?)"
ANSWER: "Probably terribly, especially if the queries are written by someone who thinks it's OK to have millions of tables. That tells me this is someone who doesn't understand databases very well."

unsatisfactory, as it does not address that the DB will contain little consistency functions and only be queried according to the hierarchical way the needs dictate. Consistency upon deletes and analytical queries can be handled in code using a layer, since my app will need to manage the RAM with care. The DB will only
*provide persistence
*be periodically updated by addition
*and be read from.

So the bottomline is that I wonder how the second design scales using MySQL. Say for instance if every query of the form "INSERT INTO / SELECT FROM tableName" is handled by a linear name search through the DB, then having many tables simply does not scale. Also any other hint/tips/experiences are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using character strings as keys?  Of course, you can declare them to be `unique`, so there are no duplicates.  But your size problems should be fixed by using auto-incremented integer ids.  If you actually need billions and billions of rows, then use a larger integer.

As for a database containing millions of *tables*.  I don't know.  I have lots of experience with many types of databases, and have never dealt with one so designed.  Primarily because it is a sign of really poor database design to have multiple "parallel" tables -- that is, tables with the same structure but different names.

Such tables are a maintenance nightmare.  They make is almost impossible to re-use queries.  You would have to use some sort of query generating tool to find the right tables for what you are doing.  They can occupy more space, because there are lots more partially filled tables.  Expressing foreign key constraints is a nightmare.  And there are more problems.

If using reasonably sized keys doesn't fix your problems, you can also look into database partitioning, where different groups of rows are stored separately.  The place to start with understanding partitioning is the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html).

Comment: Yep character strings are used as keys, which are guearanteed to be unique for TopLevel entities, but not MidLevelEntities. However if two MidLevelEntities has the same id, then they cannot belong to the same TopLevelEntity. This is the reason for using two and three primary keys. In any case, a MidLevelEntity will be retrieved from the DB using its id and parenId.

Comment: @SaniNguyen . . . You can still use composite primary keys if you like.  The components should be *integers* not *strings*.

Comment: Yep, I am using composite primary keys identified by Strings which can be translated to integers, think the DBMS should not care. What I might be needing is NoSQL (?) instead of a regular tabular DB to overcome the 10's of GB with redundant data. This may also be slow, figuring that updates and reads will need to look at large tables with one-two many columns.

Comment: @SaniNguyen . . . Of course the database cares.  You shouldn't be storing redundant strings in all those rows.  The integers would be much smaller and you can look up the string value using joins when you need them.  In addition, the indexes will be more efficient as well.